# What to put in sender.send - Google Cloud Messaging for Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I did not understand what should be in the variable registrationId

```
registrationId=?
Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, 5);
```

Can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is **registrationId**?

[Google Doc](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) says : "An ID issued by the GCM servers to the Android application that allows it to receive messages. Once the Android application has the registration ID, it sends it to the 3rd-party application server, which uses it to identify each device that has registered to receive messages for a given Android application. In other words, a registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device. "

You can think `registrationId` as a `device token` which is specific to the device, a unique identification for the device. This unique identification token or `registrationId` will help you to send `message` to the specified device only.

When you are registering `GCM` service from the `android app`, at that time registration process returns this unique id which is known as a `registrationId.